# How to use object in whole class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use `#import "PaginationTable.h"`:
This class contents properties like as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) BOOL isLoading;
```

I create an instance in:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   PaginationTable *pagination = [[PaginationTable alloc] init];
   self.pag = pagination;
}
```

Where `self.pag` is property as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) PaginationTable *pag;
```

Inside this class there is method, where I can get value of `pag`:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
 NSLog(@"Pag: %@", self.pag.isLoading);
}
```

It gives me `nil`.

How I can use `pag` inside whole class?

Comment: Where is the `NSLog` statement being called?

Comment: 1) Make sure you call `[super viewDidLoad];` inside your `viewDidLoad` method. 2) Make sure `pagination` isn't `nil` on the `self.pag = pagination;` line.

Comment: Added this in question. Seems object `PaginationTable *pagination` was died and is not available

Comment: No. `self` is still the same `self` as in any instance method in the class.

Comment: May be I must to do singlton for `PaginationTable`? `PaginationTable` gives me only fields that I fill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give nil because use %@ format. %@ format for obj but BOOL is a primitive. Try use %d.
%@ print (null) or (nil) because define BOOL like nil, Nil, NULL, nullptr

also try NSLog(@"%p", self.pag) for print point object PaginationTable